# How to generate text from loop into html?

Tags: javascript, html, react-native

I want to show my HTML from array into WebView:

```
<WebView source={{  html:       '<b>'+this.state.data.myArray[0].name+'</b>' + this.state.data.myArray[0].surname }} />
```

but I have 50 elements in the array and I am trying to generate this, using a loop for like below :

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.data.myArray.length; i++) {
    '<b>' + this.state.data.myArray[i].name + '</b>' +
        this.state.data.myArray[i].surname
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your function to set it in render method like this

```
render(){
var string = '';
  for (let i=0; i < this.state.data.myArray.length; i++){
        string = string +'<b>'+{this.state.data.myArray[i].name}+'</b>' +
        {this.state.data.myArray[i].surname}
    }
 return (
<WebView
                source={{
                    html:string
                }}
            />
 )
}
```

Or if you wish to create 50 different WebView use map

```
 render(){
     return (
     {this..state.data.myArray.map((data)=><WebView
                    source={{
                        html:'<b>'+{data.name}+'</b>'+{data.surname}
                    }}
                />)}

     )
    }
```

Comment: @helloReact i updated my ans. See if it work or else try to `console.log(string)//to see whats inside`

Comment: @helloReact try string without `{}`